Bootstrap 5 - mt-5 overrides mt-md-0 on ≥768px screen size
on medium and below medium screen sizes i have 4 cols that will be above each others, i need to give 2 cols some margin on medium and below medium screen sizes and remove it on above medium screen sizes, so i give it class mt-5 mt-md-0, but the mt-5 class overrides mt-md-0 on above medium screen sizes, am i using it the wrong way ?
import React from "react";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

function CoreValues() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid px-0">
      <div className="row px-lg-5">
        <div className="col-lg-6">
          ...
        </div>

        <div className="col-lg-6 mt-5 mt-md-0">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row mt-5 px-lg-5">
        <div className="col-lg-6">
          ...
        </div>
        <div className="col-lg-6 mt-5 mt-md-0">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CoreValues;



mt-md-0 should override mt-5 on larger screens. Without a working code snippet that demonstrates your problem, it’s difficult to see what’s happening, but you should be able to see what margin setting is being applied using the developer tools on your browser. Since you’re using Bootstrap 5, the bootstrap-5 tag would be more appropriate.

@RichDeBourke what's happening is that mt-5 overrides mt-md-0 on above medium screen sizes, i've seen that through spectating styles, here is the link in case you want to try it out <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"       rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384 EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC crossorigin="anonymous"/>

Johnny — I've created an html code snippet based on your question. If you run and expand the snippet, you can see the margin-top switching from 3rem to 0 on larger (> 768px) screens.
The attached screen capture shows mt-md-0 overriding mt-5 in developer tools.

If you are experiencing something different, it would be easiest to see what's happening if you would post a functional code snippet, rather than copying your code from your React module.


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container-fluid px-0">
    <div class="row px-lg-5">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            ...
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6 mt-5 mt-md-0">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-5 px-lg-5">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 mt-5 mt-md-0">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




i see, mine was applying multiple classes of mt-5, one from bootstrap and another one from primeflex.css, the primeflex one was overriding
